# Learndash groups content protection with tags

Tags: wordpress, memberpress, learndash

Currently, I use learndash to lock courses and memberpress to lock posts/pages tagged "premium". Learndash provides the option to lock posts/pages with learndash groups. However, it only has the option to lock contents inside post editor by selecting individual courses/groups. How can I make learndash groups to protect posts/pages tagged premium so that I can deactivate memberpress and use only learndash?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, you certainly not require the memberpress for these kind of controls.

Go to your quiz and under settings page you will see the following checkbox:

**Only registered users can take this Quiz**

After turning that ON, you will get the following message on the front-end:

**You must sign in or sign up to start the quiz.**

And it is obvious that registered users are only those, which actually purchase your course or you allow them with an identity.

Alternatively you can use another toolkit for these kind of toggles.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/toolkit-for-learndash-lms/